# iOS Firebase Push Notification for sandbox only

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I am trying to send a PUSH message to iOS using the Firebase. APNS certificate has been set up for the development and production, and It is confirmed that the remote message can be received. I think there is no way to send a message only for development in Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, there is no dev vs prod switch in the message composer.

One option is to have dev builds subscribe to topics with a _dev appended to them then only send to the _dev topics when developing.

Comment: How does Firebase then decide to which APNS endpoint it has to send the message? There is https://api.push.apple.com for production and https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com for sandbox... Is firebase sending to both at the same time? Firebase must use the same mechanism as used in https://github.com/Blackjacx/Scripts/blob/master/push/push-apns.sh and as you can see you need an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above, you cannot send directly without knowing which devices are having development build or having production build.

What you can try is

1. Based on the scheme you are running/releaseing, set a firebase property, say isDevBuild, with values Yes for dev builds and No for prodbuild.
   This property will be available for you in firebase console when you are composing the notification message.
   Based on user-property if you set the property as Yes, the notification will be sent to all devices which has a dev build.

[image]

or

2. Create a separate firebase project for dev and prod.
   This will help you in separating all your dev info (analytics, notification info) with prod info.

Hope this helps.